# module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'reduce_std'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have to use tensorflow version 1.2.1 for my coding assignment.
And I am getting this error "**module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'reduce_std**'"

> 

```
class Dense(Layer):
    def __init__(self, input_units, output_units, learning_rate=0.1):
     
        graph = tf.Graph()
        with graph.as_default():
            initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()
            self.weights = tf.Variable(initializer([input_units, output_units]))
            print(tf.reduce_std(self.weights, axis=None, keepdims=False, name=None))
            self.biases= tf.Variable(initializer([output_units,]))
```

could someone help me how to solve this?

Comment: Apparently, there is no `reduce_std` in tensorflow `1.2.1`.

Comment: Do you have any specific reason about using TF 1.2.1 ?

Comment: I am using google colab. It has the version 1.2.1.

Comment: This version is very old.Did you tried with Tensorflow 1.15 version?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to add

```
tf.math.reduce_std()
```

Also, need to check the tensorflow version first: `print("TF version:", tf.__version__)`